# conda activate on Travis CI

Tags: bash, shell, anaconda, travis-ci, conda

I am using conda 4.6.8 to test a python package in a conda env on Travis CI. I want to replace my old `source activate ENVNAME` line with the new `conda activate ENVNAME` [command](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/) in my Travis CI configuration. If I run this on Travis:

```
>>> conda update -n base conda
>>> conda init
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/condabin/conda
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/bin/conda
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/bin/conda-env
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/bin/activate
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/bin/deactivate
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xonsh/conda.xsh
no change     /home/travis/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
modified      /home/travis/.bashrc
==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==
```

How can I "close and re-open" my shell on Travis? Because otherwise I cannot activate my conda environment:

```
>>> conda create -n TEST package_names
>>> conda activate TEST
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell
See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
The command "conda activate TEST" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it is currently supported as the official doc [still uses `source` in travis.yml](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/use-conda-with-travis-ci.html).

#### What does `conda init` do?

This new command should harmonize the way users setup their shells to be able to call `conda activate`.

Actually, if you run `conda init --dry-run --verbose` you will see that it tries to source `conda.sh` from your `~/.bashrc` (assuming you're running Bash, from info mentioned in your question).

And `conda.sh` will define a `conda()` function that will catch a few commands among which `activate` and `deactivate` and dispatch to `$CONDA_EXE`:

```
conda() {
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        "$CONDA_EXE"
    else
        \local cmd="$1"
        shift
        case "$cmd" in
            activate|deactivate)
                __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@"
                ;;
            install|update|upgrade|remove|uninstall)
                "$CONDA_EXE" "$cmd" "$@" && __conda_reactivate
                ;;
            *) "$CONDA_EXE" "$cmd" "$@" ;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

So unless this function is defined in your local shell, you won't be able to call `conda activate`.

#### Hint on a solution? (*not tested for Travis CI*)

The only hint I can suggest is to try `source $(conda info --root)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` and then `conda activate`. This should do roughly the same as `conda init` **assuming you are using Bourne shell derivatives**.

For `csh` there is `$(conda info --root)/etc/profile.d/conda.csh`, and for `fish` there is `$(conda info --root)/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish`

Note: although not tested for Travis CI, this solution works for me from bash. Of course, the conda executable should be found in `PATH` for `conda info --root` to work properly.

Comment: Update: as of conda 4.6 (possibly earlier), the official docs have moved to `conda activate`. They still *do not* use `conda init`, instead sourcing the script directly, as in this answer.